# What animals are represented by the members of the 501st Joint Fighter Wing?

Tags: strike-witches

In the ending credits of the second season of *Strike Witches*, it shows that each member of the 501st has a coat of arms which an image of the animal they represent when they use their magic.

Some are easy to tell while for others I'm not 100% sure (apart from 2), half are cats and half are dogs, the 2 odd ones are a rabbit and what I think is supposed to be a tanuki.

I am wondering, what animals the 501st JFW members represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Commanding Officer**

Minna-Dietlinde Wilcke - Gray Wolf

**Commanding Officer in battle**

Sakamoto Mio - Doberman

**Members**

Gertrud Barkhorn - German Pointer

Erica Hartmann - Dachshund

Perrine H. Clostermann - Chartreux

Francesca Lucchini - Black panther

Eila Ilmatar Juutilainen - Black Fox

Charlotte E. Yeager - White Rabbit

Sanya V. Litvyak - Black cat

Lynette Bishop - Scottish Fold

Miyafuji Yoshika - Mameshiba